# Adding Variables to href link for d3/javascript object tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip, d3.js, href

So here's what I'm doing:

```
var selection = canvas.selectAll("circle").data(data);      
selection.enter().append("circle")
    selection
      .attr("title", function(d){ return "<div class='candtip'>"+d.Name+"<br /><a
        href='Twitter.com/'+d.Twitter><img src='Twitter.png'/></a></div>"})
```

So for each element I have a tooltip show up that shows that displays Twitter's logo and then I would like that when you click on that picture it brings you to that persons Twitter page but I can't seem to get the href part to work correctly. The way the data is set up is that 'd.Twitter' is a variable that holds the id of that persons Twitter page, so if the page was Twitter.com/OprahWinfrey , then d.Twitter = OprahWinfrey.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var selection = canvas.selectAll("circle").data(data);      
selection.enter().append("circle")
    selection // no need for this here
      .attr("title", function(d){ return "<div class='candtip'>" + d.Name + "<br /><a
        href='Twitter.com/" + d.Twitter + "'><img src='Twitter.png'/></a></div>"})
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which browser you are using that can render html in tooltips created by `title` attributes. AFAIK, you can only put plain text in tooltips (i.e., in `title` attributes). If you want clickable html tooltips you need to create them yourself, e.g., using SVG tags and groups.

Here is a rather complete example that you can dissect for you purpose:

```
<style>
    circle { fill: #8ad; }
    rect   { fill: white; stroke: #eee; }
    g.candtip         { display: none;  }
    a:hover g.candtip { display: block; }
    g.candtip:hover   { display: block; }
</style>

<svg width="600" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></svg>

<script type="text/javascript">
var getY         = function(d,i) { return 100 + i*100; }
var getTranslate = function(d,i) { return "translate(100,"+getY(d,i)+")"; }
var data = [ 
    {Name: "Uwe Jugel", Twitter: "ubunatic"},
    {Name: "Juve",      Twitter: "ubunatic"}
]
var canvas = d3.select("svg")
var selection = canvas.selectAll("a").data(data)
var newLinks = selection.enter().append("a")

newLinks
.attr("xlink:target","_blank")
.attr("xlink:href", function(d,i) { return "http://twitter.com/"+d.Twitter; })

newLinks.append("circle")
.attr("cx", 100)
.attr("cy", getY)
.attr("r", 40)

var newTooltips = newLinks.append("g").attr("class", "candtip")
newTooltips.attr("transform", getTranslate );

newTooltips.append("rect")
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("width", 100)
.attr("height", 30)

newTooltips.append("text")
.attr("x", 30)
.attr("y", 20)
.text( function(d,i) { return d.Name; } )

newTooltips.append("svg:image")
.attr("xlink:href", "https://twitter.com/images/resources/twitter-bird-16x16.png")
.attr("x", 5)
.attr("y", 5)
.attr("width",  "16px")
.attr("height", "16px")   
</script>
```

It basically sets up a hoverable `circle` and a tooltip group `g.candtip`. The tooltippyness is done via simple `:hover` rules. The links in SVG are done via `<a>` + `xlink:href`. All data is read and transformed by d3 + d3.style helper functions.